# Java create regex Groups

Tags: java, regex

I have a text containing some important information I want to extrakt. 
The important information is marked in curly brackets. There are several different "markings" of the important text to divide it into groups.

An Example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit **{this is important}\GROUP1** amet, consetetur
>   sadipscing elitr, sed diam **{also Important}\GROUP1** nonumy eirmod
>   tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, **{not so
>   important}\GROUP2** sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
>   **{slightly important}\GROUP3** justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.

To find these "important text" blocks I use regex (take the stuff between "{" and "\GROUP1"):

```
Pattern regexGroup1 = Pattern.compile("(\\{(.*?)\\GROUP1"));  
Matcher regexMatcher = regexGroup1.matcher(data);  
regexMatcher.group();
```

to find the GROUP1 textchunks.

```
 Pattern regexGroup2 = Pattern.compile("(\\{(.*?)\\GROUP2"));  
 Matcher regexMatcher = regexGroup2.matcher(data);  
 regexMatcher.group();
```

to find the GROUP2 textchunks.... etc.

Is there a way to make only 1 regex to find all those groups at once and access them with regexMatcher.group(1-3) ?

something like this:
regexMatcher.group(1) output:

> this is important
>   also Important

regexMatcher.group(2) output:

> not so important

regexMatcher.group(3) output:

> slightly important

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a slightly different `Pattern`, with two groups. Like,

```
Pattern regexGroup = Pattern.compile("(\\{(.*?)\\GROUP(\\d+)");  
Matcher regexMatcher = regexGroup.matcher(data);
```

Then you might access the data with `regexMatcher.group(1)` and `regexMatcher.group(2)` (examining the result of the second for the *importance*).

Comment: ah I see.
But the chunks are not always marked as "GROUP1-?". I used this as an example (my bad).   
It should work with {}\GROUP, {}\PERSON, {}\ANIMAL, etc...
Its a text annotated by some kind of NER Extractor.

Comment: The same idea, just use a regex to match `([GROUP|PERSON|ANIMAL])`

Comment: `(\\{(.*?)\\}\\\\(GROUP|PERSON)(\\d+)`